# Android, Javascript, Rhino, JSON

Tags: javascript, android, json, scripting, rhino

After long search in repo folders I found rhino1_7R2.jar for Android at http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/browse/rhino/rhino1_7R2.jar Unfortunately 1_7R3 is not there.

The script I'm using uses JSON.stringify function which is not present in 1_7R2. There is the JSON2.js file for Rhino but I don't know the proper way to load it at run time. Documentation and example codes are weak. Should I load it as a string and prepend on the running script? Or there is a better way?

I'm using JavaScript to dynamically evaluate some calculations in a loop. I really want to avoid prepending the JSON2.js every time I call a javascript function. Spent almost one day to find out Rhino has supported JSON object at late version and nobody bothered to port it to Android. Looks like another open source project lacking support.

Should i give up and consider using WebView method? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you hava some JavaScript script that you want to run by Rhino. If you want to load another JavaScript file, you can use `load` function:

```
load("/your/path/json2.js");
```

After that call your script can use json2 library.

```
var testStr = '{"test" : {"a": "aval", "b" : "bval"}}';
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(testStr);
var a = jsonObj.test.a;
```

Comment: Which folder does it read from? res/assets? I'm going to try first thing in the morning. By the way still considering WebView for the overhead of loading json2 file each time i run a small script. Or maybe I could load once and reuse the context which will make it more complex. Ideas/experience on performance will also be appreciated.

Comment: You need to specify full path to json2.js in load call. json2.js is pretty small. As a matter of fact you might even consider to copy its content to your script.